# Which preposition do you use when we have (adjective) and (adjective) (preposition)?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

For example, you usually say "happy about something" and "proud of something", but when you want to say both, do you say:

> *Happy and proud of something*,
>   *Happy and proud about something*,
>   or
>   *Happy about and proud of something*?

Is there a general rule to follow in cases such as these?

Comment: I typically would use the first or third one, although the third one is a little clunky. That said, I'm not confident enough about my usage to actually make it an answer.

Comment: Hugely related and probably a duplicate: [Two prepositions or one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17182/can-i-use-two-prepositions-in-this-example-or-is-one-better) -- if you need two different prepositions, you can't just use one.

Answer (score 1):

Except if the two(or more) adjectives or verbs take the same preposition (as in happy and sad about... or I insist and am bent on...), I think one should state the appropriate prepositions for each word. I am happy with and interested in you... she is married to and obsessed with him...so in you case, I would say I AM HAPPY ABOUT AND PROUD OF...(your achievement etc).